# Effective ways to apply Weakness as a Hunter

Tags: destiny-2

With the new Void sub-class changes Bungie are rolling out new bounties around the void status effects.

Such as this one...

> Defeat combatants in Vanguard playlists by weakening them with Void.

[image: Defeat combatants in Vanguard playlists by weakening them with Void.]

So far the only way I can find to apply Weakness is using the Hunters Trappers Ambush

> Trapper’s Ambush: Players can activate Quickfall in Destiny 2 to spend their melee charge and dive to the ground, creating a smoke cloud upon impact. Enemies caught in the cloud are weakened and allies become invisible. Also, Snare Bombs, upon attaching to surfaces or enemies, cause the player and nearby allies to become invisible.

Is this the only method Hunters have to apply Weakness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trapper's Ambush is not the only method to apply Weakness.

The fastest way that I've found to apply weakness effectively is to apply the fragment 'Echo of Undermining', this makes any void grenade weaken a target (I personally like Vortex Grenade). Snare Bomb also weakens targets. I would also recommend using the fragment 'Echo of Remnants' to get extra duration on any lingering grenade (Vortex Grenade, Void Wall, Void Spike or Axion Bolt)

Keep in mind, the fragment 'Echo of Undermining' removes 20 of your discipline points, so if you really want to get this bounty done fast, you should run a high discipline, grenade focused build.

Comment: Does this fragment combine with the suppression grenade for both suppression and weakness?

Comment: @Neon1024 I haven't tested that, but I'm sure that would work, most things in Destiny stack/combine unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The Nightstalker super "Deadfall" applies weakness to all enemies in range of the impact zone. If you use it in combination with the hunter exotic boots "Orpheus Rig", you get approximately 50% return super immediately and the rest can be generated from the orbs from slain enemies.